# Spring Integration - http inbound

Tags: spring, spring-integration

im trying to make a http inbound but when i print my message the payload its empty, what am i missing here?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class HttpInboundGateway {

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow inGate1() {
      log.info("Initializing inbound gateway...");
      return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/")
            .requestPayloadType(PayloadObj.class))
            .channel("transfer_next_channel")
            .get();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "transfer_next_channel")
  public MessageHandler handler() {
      return new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("myHandlerPayload: " + message.getPayload());
            System.out.println("myHandlerHeader: " + message.getHeaders());
        }
    };
  }
}
```

PayloadObj class expected:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PayloadObj {

    String name;
    String job;
}
```

EDIT 1: As requested

Curl from Postman

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9090/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name":"Marcos",
    "job":"Dev Jr"
}'
```

Print from handler:

```
myHandlerPayload: {} --- Payload
myHandlerHeader: {content-length=46, http_requestMethod=GET, 
host=localhost:9090, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:9090/, 
connection=keep-alive, id=e67aef3d-938a-7ac3-eb7d-ddaf9cd74f4e, 
contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, 
deflate, br, user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.28.4, accept=*/*, 
timestamp=1642168826837}
```

Comment: Please, share with us what exactly a request. Does it have that required `Content-Type = application/json` header? Do you mean that you really got your `PayloadObj` instance, but its `name` and `job` are empty?

Comment: Done, looks like payloadObj inst getting to handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9090/'

You do `GET` request. This way the body of the request is ignored.
And only request params are transferred as payload. Since you don't have those as well, that means the payload is empty `Map`.

Consider to use `POST` or `PUT` instead.
And learn more about an HTTP protocol and its method specifics.

Comment: I knew it was something silly that i was missing, omg. Thank you for the answer.